# How Do I Make A Common PHP File To A Directory With .htaccess?

Tags: php, .htaccess, url

I'm looking to handle the URL's except homepage with a common PHP file. This is just like a PHP $_GET request except the difference that there would be no parameter. It'll be just like a file.

Ex- `http://localhost/` - This should be managed by index.php file as usual.
`http://localhost/ANYTHINGHERE` - This should be thrown to a custom PHP file which would then decide what to do.

Actually, I'm working on a project where I need to hide the URL information from the users. So, the file that would manage the ANYTHINGHERE URL would actually access a directory localhost/i/.

Thanks and waiting for best response!

Comment: Show us that you at least researched this yourself before asking.

Comment: I'm not clear what you're asking for @CBroe

Comment: I want you to show/tell us, what you have tried to far to solve this problem on your own.

Comment: [[Facepalm]], that's what I was asking for. I'm struck because I'm unaware of .htaccess. I did some URL rewriting but was unable to do it.

Comment: keywords: single access point pattern, php routing [e.g. klein, toro...].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this you need two parts:

First: .htaccess which redirects all accesses to your domain passed to a php script (index.php here):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule (.*) index.php/$1
```

Second: In index.php you get the user-entered URI as `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']` (starting with `/`)

This, however, makes all requests to go through the index.php script (depending on the location of index.php you could also get an endless recursion, so read on ;) ). Normally one doesn't want that (e.g., images should be served directly by the web server). Thus, one normally uses (i.e., existing directories, files and links are served by the web server directly):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule (.*) index.php/$1
```

If this should take place in a subdirectory you need to add `RewriteBase /subdirectory` directly after `RewriteEngine On`.

If you don't want to use `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']`you can also use `RewriteRule (.*) index.php?url=$1 [QSA]`, then you get the user entered URI as `$_GET['url']`.

This requires `mod_rewrite` to be loaded on the server.

See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html.

Comment: Sure. But I don't want it to redirect the control to index.php. Maybe some other file. Then how do I specify that on .htaccess. (I'm sorry I'm too bad at .htaccess, don't know about it)

Comment: Just replace index.php by some other filename you want to use.

Comment: Hello. Thanks, but RewriteEnging On in .htaccess gives me Server error! 500. Any guesses?

Comment: Then mod_rewrite isn't loaded - ask the admig to load that module. Do you have root access (what system is running on that server?)

Comment: Nevermind, the first line goes fine now. But RewriteRule (.*) index.php/$1 gives me error. I'm putting it like this:

RewriteEngine On <linebreak instead of this>
RewriteRule (.*) dir1/index.php/$1   

I'm running it on my localhost apache server. I'm doing project inside dir1 and want that other stuff to redirect to that specific file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59418/discussion-between-mehul-mohan-and-mrtux).